# Understanding the issues of bit copying

Tags: c++, count, copy-constructor

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
blueberry bitCopy(blueberry a) {
  cout << "bitCopy " << blueberry::blQuantity << endl;
  return a;
}

void howMany() {
  cout << blueberry::blQuantity << endl;
}

int main() {
  blueberry firstBl;
  howMany();
  bitCopy(firstBl);
  howMany();
}
```

class blueberry:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class blueberry {
private:
static int blQuantity;
public:
    blueberry();
    ~blueberry() {
    blQuantity--;
    }
    friend blueberry bitCopy(blueberry a);
    friend void howMany();
}; 

#endif

int blueberry::blQuantity = 0;

blueberry::blueberry() {
    blQuantity++;
};
```

class blueberry is just some class that has a static int value blQuantity that increments in the constructor each time an object is created, and decrements in the destructor each time an object goes out of scope.

The read out from this program is:

```
1
bitCopy 1
-1
```

I was expecting 0 at the end rather than -1. Can someone explain this please?

PLEASE do not tell me I require a copy constructor. I am not trying to fix this code so that the object count works. I am instead trying to understand how this works and why the blQuantity is not the value I expect.

Comment: Please don't post code with `void main`. Can you fix that? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code, but I guess you're also decrementing the count in the destructor (hence the expectation of zero), and not incrementing it in the copy constructor (hence an extra decrement when the function parameter is destroyed, without a matching increment when it was created by copying the local variable). You should post a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain why you expect what you expect, if you want a good answer.

Comment: Also, this isn't "bit copying", whatever you mean by that. It's just regular object copying.

Comment: In destructor, are you decrementing `blQuantity`...

Comment: @MikeSeymour: who knows.... Have you seen the code?

Comment: If everything (which you haven't shown) was written correctly, you should expect 1 at the end rather than -1 or 0 because there is one instance still alive.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: No I haven't seen the code, which is why I didn't answer, and suggested the OP improve the question so we can.

Comment: After your edit showing the actual class definition:  As per my answer and other's comments, the problem is **you have not defined a copy constructor.**

Comment: Ok that was a bad post, apologies, I have made edits. Mike Seymour, I have not created a copy constructor deliberately so that the compiler just copies the values of that object bit-by-bit. That is what I refer to when I say bit-copying.

interjay, no, what I have done is deliberate and I am trying to understand what is happening rather than writing an effective piece of code. I expect 0, despite that one object is still in scope.

Comment: delicateLatticeworkFever, it seems my question was not clear. What I want is an explanation of why blQuantity has this value rather than a solution. I do not want the object count to work properly, I want an understanding of what is happening in the above code.

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie: if you want other users to be notified of your comments, you must prepend a '@' to their username, as I have just done. Otherwise, by default, only the author of the question or answer you are commenting is notified. That said, 1) You are not showing the destructor yet (is it `blQuantity--`?) and 2) Try to describe, step by step, when you expect the counter to increase/decrease, and why. This way, answers will be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> class blueberry is just some class that has a static int value blQuantity that increments in the constructor each time an object is created, and decrements in the destructor each time an object goes out of scope.

Are you sure that's each and every time one is created?  I think there is something you've missed.

```
blueberry bitCopy(blueberry a)
```

That's pass-by-value; i.e., `blueberry a` here is *a copy* of what was submitted to `bitCopy()`.  That invokes blueberry's **[copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Three)**, which you have not defined.  The compiler thus creates a simple one for you, which copies over any member values from the original object -- but it does NOT increment anything.  If you want that, you'll have to define:

```
blueberry::blueberry (const blueberry&) // copy constructor
blueberry& operator= (const blueberry&) // copy assignment operator
```

You may also want a move constructor and move assignment operator -- see that wikipedia article about the "rule of three (or five)"
 I linked in the above paragraph.

The reason `blQuantity` is -1 at the end is because there are actually *two* copies made with `bitCopy()`, one for the parameter and one for the return value.  If you change it to:

```
blueberry bitCopy (blueberry &a)
```

I.e., using pass-by-reference, there will only be one copy and `blQuantity` will be 0 afterward.  If you then make the return value `void`, there will be no copies made and `blQuantity` should be 1.

---

Here's a demonstration of the roles of the copy constructor and `operator=` (copy assignment operator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        string x;
        A (string s) : x(s) {
            cout << "A con " << "(" << x << ")\n";
        }
        A (const A& other) : x(other.x) {
            x.append("-copy");
            cout << "A copy " << "(" << x << ")\n";
        }
        A& operator= (const A& other) {
            x = other.x;
            x.append("[=]");
            cout << "A assign " << "(" << x << ")\n";
            return *this;
        }
        ~A () { cerr << x << " A bye!\n"; }
};


A test (A a) {
    return a;
}


int main (void) {
    A a("#1");
    cout << "test()\n";
    A b = test(a);
    cout << "Copy assign:\n";
    b = a;
    cout << "Exiting...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'll step through the output from this:

```
A con (#1)
test()
A copy (#1-copy)
A copy (#1-copy-copy)
#1-copy A bye!
```

The first line is from `A a("#1")`.  The last three lines are a result of `A b = test(a)`.  The first one is copying in the parameter, `A test (test a)`.  The second is the creation of the return value, which is a copy of the parameter, so the tag on the object is now `#1-copy-copy`.  That initializes `b` in `main()`.  When `test()` exits, the parameter object is destroyed, `#1-copy A bye!`.

```
Copy assign:
A assign (#1[=])
```

This is from `b = a` in `main()`.  **Notice that the previous version of `b` is not destroyed.**  This is because copy assignment is meant to turn one object into a copy of another; neither object is destroyed, but the contents of the target object is presumably changed, hence `b`'s tag is now `#1[=]`.  So predictably:

```
Exiting...
#1[=] A bye!
#1 A bye!
```

When the program ends, `a` and `b` are destroyed.

If you change the signature of `test()` to:

```
A& test (A &a)
```

You'll get this output:

```
A con (#1)
test()
A copy (#1-copy)
Copy assign:
A assign (#1[=])
Exiting...
#1[=] A bye!
#1 A bye!
```

Only two objects are ever created, `a` via the constructor and `b` via the copy con; both of them are not destroyed until the end.  If you then do not use the return value of `test()`, only one object is ever created.

Comment: delicateLatticeworkFever, thank you for the useful information. What I am really after here is an explanation of what is happening. I am aware that for the object count to work in this situation I would require a copy constructor. However I would like to understand what is happening in the code in its current form

Comment: Okay -- you created a `blueberry` and check `blQuantity`, which is now 1 because it was incremented in the constructor.  You then call `bitCopy()`, which creates a new blueberry *using the compiler defined copy constructor*, which does not increment anything, so `blQuantity` is still 1.   There's a bit regarding RVO which I think I was wrong about (have edited the last paragraph about this) -- the compiler did not optimize the return value *which is also a copy*, therefore there are two copies made, both of which are destroyed, so you end up with -1.

Comment: If you create the copy con and include some output, you can watch two copies being made by that call to `bitCopy()`.

Comment: Thanks that was extremely helpful! So just to check, if I was to set a second blueberry equal to the output of bitCopy(firstBl) would the compiler still destroy the temporary return variable afterwards?

Comment: It would not be destroyed right away if you used `blueberry x = bitCopy(firstVl)` because the copy would be `x`.   If you write the copy con to produce some output ("blueberry copied!"), and give each blueberry an id string of some sort in the normal constructor (so you could do, e.g., "blueberry A1 copied!" in the copy con), you can fool around with this and see what's going on.    I've added an example above to demonstrate what I mean.